# Is there a cleaner way to split delimited text into data structures?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, text

I have this code:

```
    private IEnumerable<FindReplacePair> ConstructFindReplacePairs(string inputFilePath)
    {
        var arrays = from line in File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(inputFilePath))
                    select line.Split('|');

        var pairs = from array in arrays
                    select new FindReplacePair { Find = array[0], Replace = array[1] };

        return pairs;
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is a clean linq syntax to do this operation in only one query, because it feels like there should be.

I tried chaining the from clauses (a SelectMany), but it splits up the data too much and I could not get to the separate arrays to select from (instead I got individual strings one at a time).

Comment: What makes you feel this is not clean? Why is a one liner so much better?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why I didn't think that was clean. I don't have any great objection to doing it this way (it works, after all, and it's not horrible!) and looking back at it it's better than I remembered - originally though, I intended it to be one action.  To answer your question, it's not inherently better as a single query, but since that's what I originally wanted and I couldn't get it working I asked StackOverflow and have now learned at least two new things about this type of linq operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<FindReplacePair> ConstructFindReplacePairs(string inputFilePath)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(inputFilePath))
               .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
               .Select(array => new FindReplacePair { 
                          Find = array[0], 
                          Replace = array[1] 
                });
}
```

OR

```
IEnumerable<FindReplacePair> ConstructFindReplacePairs(string inputFilePath)
{
    return from line in File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(inputFilePath))
           let array = line.Split('|')
           select new FindReplacePair {
              Find = array[0], Replace = array[1]
           };
}
```

You can also add *where* condition to check if array has more than one element.

Comment: the let syntax is what I was originally trying (and failed) to do, so thanks.  I'm aware that there is currently no correctness checking, but in this case I'd rather it threw a messy exception and complained instead of carrying on with an incomplete dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is *cleaner*, just a little bit shorter.

```
IEnumerable<FindReplacePair> allFindReplacePairs = File.ReadLines(inputFilePath)
    .Select(l => new FindReplacePair { Find = l.Split('|')[0], Replace = l.Split('|')[1] });
```

Note that i'm using `File.ReadLines` which does not need to read all lines into memory first. it works like a `StreamReader`.

Comment: +1 for the File.ReadLines, I didn't remember it existed and it would probably be a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes down to prettifying LINQ, I usually write out simple loop and Resharper will suggest a better LINQ optimisation, e.g.

```
foreach (var split in File.ReadAllLines(inputFilePath).Select(l => l.Split('|')))
    yield return new FindReplacePair { Find = split[0], Replace = split[1] };
```

R# convertes it to

```
return File.ReadAllLines(inputFilePath).Select(l => l.Split('|')).Select(split => new FindReplacePair { Find = split[0], Replace = split[1] });
```

That said you might as well use builtin type, e.g. `.ToDictionary(l => l[0], l => l[1])` or add a method on `FindReplacePair`, i.e.

```
return File.ReadAllLines(inputFilePath).Select(l => l.Split('|')).Select(FindReplacePair.Create);

public static FindReplacePair Create(string[] split)
{
    return new FindReplacePair { Find = split.First(), Replace = split.Last() };
}
```